# PostgreSQL: Inserting & Deleting in Same Statement or Transaction?

Tags: postgresql

I'm building a React application with an Express.js back-end.  Both are being built with TypeScript.  The DB is Postgres.

In my app, I have media files and tags.  The former are stored in a `media` table and the latter are stored in a `tags` table.  There's also a bridge table that connects them called `media_tags`.

I'm working on allowing users to edit which tags belong to which media files.  Let's imagine that a given media file has 3 tags attached: `city`, `architecture`, `transit`.  Now a user comes along and wants to remove `transit` and add `dog`.  This is all well handled by the front-end.  In this use case, the following tags will be sent to my back-end code:

- city
- architecture
- dog

My plan is to gather the existing tags for the selected media files(s) to establish a baseline of what tags are currently attached.  Then, through inference, I'll be able to add `dog` and remove `transit`.  This logic seems quite straightforward.

What I'm unclear about is what is the best SQL approach to effect these changes with the least number of calls to the DB.  Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: The most effective way is for frontend to explicitly send "delete transit" and "add dog", instead of sending the current state. So that backend can simply run these operations instead of doing heavier computations. Backend can run them all in a single call.

Comment: I appreciate you responding.  However, I completely disagree with your assertion.  You've stated that frontend should be making decisions about the business logic on the backend.  This seems absolutely incorrect to me.

Comment: How is that different from frontend sending entire state - isn't that making a decision as well, except a different one? I don't get your objection. Frontend has to send a user's intention to the backend. And frontend has to understand the business logic, otherwise how would it know which endpoints to call? The intention is: delete this, add that. And sending entire state vs sending updates is only a matter of implementation. But they fulfill the same requirement, with different advantages and disadvantages. Or maybe I don't understand what you mean by "frontend making decisions"?

Comment: I think we just have different philosophies about separation of concerns.  With GET requests, the BE doesn't need to know how the data it provides will be displayed.  With POST & PATCH requests, the FE shouldn't have to know how the BE will process it.  I do see your point about the FE able to provide more explicit info about what has been added and what has been removed but still adamantly feel it's the BE's job to sort out the logic of what to do with that information.

Comment: "the FE shouldn't have to know how the BE will process it." And where exactly in my solution FE knows how BE will process the data? FE only knows: I need to call BE to add and delete stuff. What information BE wants and how it processes it, is a detail, a piece of contract. Both my and yours idea are conceptually **exactly** the same. Except my implementation is simply more efficient. This has nothing to do with separation of concerns. It is simply an optimized API. And like seriously optimized.